# Transfer content of email to C# page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have created one web-form that contains controls to add name, date of birth, gender info of user with add button, once add button clicked that info goes to database.
But i have my mailbox, for eg. gmail some mails are coming in inbox that contains info same as earlier(Name, Date of birth, gender etc.). So can i have functionality to transfer that inbox data to my database?

Comment: Can i transfer data same like in c# page from one mail to database eg. i got one new mail that contains info aaa, male then this info shoulg go to the table having field (name,gender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can.

There are a lot of libraries that you can leverage to make it trivial to check a Gmail account.  Here is just one:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/

Here is sample code for fetching all of your e-mails:

```
public static List<Message> FetchAllMessages(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl, string username, string password)
{
    // The client disconnects from the server when being disposed
    using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
    {
        // Connect to the server
        client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

        // Authenticate ourselves towards the server
        client.Authenticate(username, password);

        // Get the number of messages in the inbox
        int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

        // We want to download all messages
        List<Message> allMessages = new List<Message>(messageCount);

        // Messages are numbered in the interval: [1, messageCount]
        // Ergo: message numbers are 1-based.
        // Most servers give the latest message the highest number
        for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
        {
            allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
        }

        // Now return the fetched messages
        return allMessages;
    }
}
```

You'll still need to go through each one and determine if it's valid for your database and then grab the data and insert it into the database; but it should be pretty straight-forward (and almost identical to what you are already doing)

For GMail you can use the following to get your mail:

```
List<Message> myMail = FetchAllMessages("pop.gmail.com", 995, true, "MyEmail@gmail.com", "mysupersecretpasswordshhhhh!");
```

Comment: here hostname,port values should be mail server if i want to transfer gmail mail to c# page then hostname & port will be of gmail???

Comment: List<Message> myMail = FetchAllMessages("pop.gmail.com", 995, true, "MyEmail@gmail.com", "mysupersecretpasswordshhhhh!");